# Ocultar div excepto imagen con jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

***Tengo el siguiente DIV :***

```
 <div id="overlays" style="background-image: url(http://agar.io/img/background.png); position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 200; margin-top: -20px">
```

Al jugar desaparece el div y al perder vuelve a aparecer

```
function hideESCOverlay() {
        escOverlay = false;
        wjQuery("#overlays").hide();
    }

    function showESCOverlay(arg) {
        escOverlay = true;
        userNickName = null;
        wjQuery("#overlays").fadeIn(350);
    }
```

Mi problema es que quiero que al jugar 1 vez una vez desaparece el overlays , desaparezca la imagen del overlay para siempre pero que no desaparezca el overlays

Osea voy a jugar y desaparece el overlay y pierdo y reaparece el overlay sin su imagen de background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es cambiar el atributo CSS `image-background` a `none`:

```js
function hideESCOverlay() {
  escOverlay = false;
  $("#overlays").hide();
}
function showESCOverlay(arg) {
  escOverlay = true;
  userNickName = null;
  $("#overlays").css('background-image', 'none');
  $("#overlays").fadeIn(350);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="overlays" style="background-image: url(http://agar.io/img/background.png);">Hola</div>

<button onclick="hideESCOverlay()">Ocultar</button>
<button onclick="showESCOverlay()">Mostrar</button>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias